# Aggregating data at feature and time both

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe at 10 minute interval, how I can aggregate it at one categorical feature and at the time of 2 hours and then calculate the average of other two features and first value of third feature

My sample data looks like follows in pyspark. I want to group by on 'ind' and at the time of 2 hours on 'date' and then calculate the mean of 'sal' and the first value of 'imp'

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

 a = sqlContext.createDataFrame([["Anand", "2020-02-01 16:00:00", 12, "ba"], 
                            ["Anand", "2020-02-01 16:10:00", 14,"sa"], 
                            ["Carl", "2020-02-01 16:00:00", 16,"da"], 
                            ["Carl", "2020-02-01 16:10:00", 12,"ga"],
                            ["Eric", "2020-02-01 16:o0:00", 24, "sa"]], ['ind', "date","sal","imp"])
a.show()

|  ind|               date|sal|imp|
+-----+-------------------+---+---+
|Anand|2020-02-01 16:00:00| 12| ba|
|Anand|2020-02-01 16:10:00| 14| sa|
| Carl|2020-02-01 16:00:00| 16| da|
| Carl|2020-02-01 16:10:00| 12| ga|
| Eric|2020-02-01 16:o0:00| 24| sa|
```

I have no idea how I can mix category feature and time(2hrs) in groupby Pyspark. I know how to do it in Pandas. But my real data is huge. Any Suggestions?

Comment: This is a standard Spark SQL question, and it has nothing to do with `machine-learning`, `pandas`, or `scikit-learn` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Can you add expected output to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To better generate the query I extended your case with few time examples

```
a = spark.createDataFrame([["Anand", "2020-02-01 16:00:00", 12, "ba"], 
                            ["Anand", "2020-02-01 16:10:00", 14,"sa"],
                           ["Anand", "2020-02-01 17:10:00", 14,"sa"],
                           ["Anand", "2020-02-01 18:10:00", 14,"sa"],
                           ["Anand", "2020-02-01 19:10:00", 14,"sa"],
                           ["Anand", "2020-02-01 20:10:00", 14,"sa"],
                           ["Anand", "2020-02-01 21:10:00", 14,"sa"],
                           ["Anand", "2020-02-01 22:10:00", 14,"sa"],
                           ["Anand", "2020-02-01 23:10:00", 14,"sa"],
                           ["Anand", "2020-02-01 00:10:00", 14,"sa"],
                           ["Anand", "2020-02-01 01:10:00", 14,"sa"],
                           ["Anand", "2020-02-01 02:10:00", 14,"sa"],
                           ["Anand", "2020-02-01 03:10:00", 14,"sa"],
                           ["Anand", "2020-02-01 04:10:00", 14,"sa"],
                           ["Anand", "2020-02-01 05:10:00", 14,"sa"],
                           ["Anand", "2020-02-01 06:10:00", 14,"sa"],
                           ["Anand", "2020-02-01 07:10:00", 14,"sa"],
                           ["Anand", "2020-02-01 08:10:00", 14,"sa"],
                           ["Anand", "2020-02-01 09:10:00", 14,"sa"],
                            ["Carl", "2020-02-01 16:00:00", 16,"da"], 
                            ["Carl", "2020-02-01 16:10:00", 12,"ga"],
                            ["Eric", "2020-02-01 16:00:00", 24, "sa"]], ['ind', "date","sal","imp"])

newa=a.withColumn('EveryTwoHour',f.when(f.hour(f.col('date').cast(t.TimestampType()))%2==0,
                                   f.hour(f.col('date').cast(t.TimestampType()))).otherwise(
                                   f.hour(f.col('date').cast(t.TimestampType()))+1))

newa.groupBy('ind','EveryTwoHour').agg(f.avg('sal'),f.first('imp')).orderBy('ind','EveryTwoHour').show()

+-----+------------+--------+-----------------+
|  ind|EveryTwoHour|avg(sal)|first(imp, false)|
+-----+------------+--------+-----------------+
|Anand|           0|    14.0|               sa|
|Anand|           2|    14.0|               sa|
|Anand|           4|    14.0|               sa|
|Anand|           6|    14.0|               sa|
|Anand|           8|    14.0|               sa|
|Anand|          10|    14.0|               sa|
|Anand|          16|    13.0|               ba|
|Anand|          18|    14.0|               sa|
|Anand|          20|    14.0|               sa|
|Anand|          22|    14.0|               sa|
|Anand|          24|    14.0|               sa|
| Carl|          16|    14.0|               da|
| Eric|          16|    24.0|               sa|
+-----+------------+--------+-----------------+
```

There are multiple ways to do it, this is just one of them.

To perform the aggregation over every two hour, we are creating a new column for every even hour and then aggregating on that.

```
a.withColumn('EveryTwoHour',f.when(f.hour(f.col('date').cast(t.TimestampType()))%2==0,
                                   f.hour(f.col('date').cast(t.TimestampType()))).otherwise(
    f.hour(f.col('date').cast(t.TimestampType()))+1)).show()

+-----+-------------------+---+---+------------+
|  ind|               date|sal|imp|EveryTwoHour|
+-----+-------------------+---+---+------------+
|Anand|2020-02-01 16:00:00| 12| ba|          16|
|Anand|2020-02-01 16:10:00| 14| sa|          16|
|Anand|2020-02-01 17:10:00| 14| sa|          18|
|Anand|2020-02-01 18:10:00| 14| sa|          18|
|Anand|2020-02-01 19:10:00| 14| sa|          20|
|Anand|2020-02-01 20:10:00| 14| sa|          20|
|Anand|2020-02-01 21:10:00| 14| sa|          22|
|Anand|2020-02-01 22:10:00| 14| sa|          22|
|Anand|2020-02-01 23:10:00| 14| sa|          24|
|Anand|2020-02-01 00:10:00| 14| sa|           0|
|Anand|2020-02-01 01:10:00| 14| sa|           2|
|Anand|2020-02-01 02:10:00| 14| sa|           2|
|Anand|2020-02-01 03:10:00| 14| sa|           4|
|Anand|2020-02-01 04:10:00| 14| sa|           4|
|Anand|2020-02-01 05:10:00| 14| sa|           6|
|Anand|2020-02-01 06:10:00| 14| sa|           6|
|Anand|2020-02-01 07:10:00| 14| sa|           8|
|Anand|2020-02-01 08:10:00| 14| sa|           8|
|Anand|2020-02-01 09:10:00| 14| sa|          10|
| Carl|2020-02-01 16:00:00| 16| da|          16|
+-----+-------------------+---+---+------------+
```

So here if i am fetching the hour and if it is even than no change and if the hour is odd i am adding 1 to it to make it next even hour.

I hope it explains the logic.

Comment: Hi Shubham, It is really helpful. You would like to add some explanation on twohour column creation. It will help me better

Comment: @ManuSharma Updated the answer

Comment: Hi, how can I resample same pyspark dataframe on date and every two hours